# org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, repository

*LoginRepository*

```java
@Repository
public class LoginRepository {
    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    
    public List logDetails(Student st) {
        List list=hibernateTemplate.find("select email,password from Student where email='?' and password='?'",st.getEmail(),st.getPassword());
        return list;
    }
}
```

*LoginService*

```java
@Service
public class LoginService {
    @Autowired
    private LoginRepository logRepo;

    public List serLogin(Student s) {
        List li = logRepo.logDetails(s);
        return li;
    }

}
```

*LoginController*

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private LoginService logSer;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Student s = new Student();
        map.put("log", s);
        System.out.println("Inside Login Controller");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveLog", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveLogin(@ModelAttribute("log") Student s, Map<String, Object> map) {
        List list = logSer.serLogin(s);
        if (list == null) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            map.put("log", s);
            return "home";
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/SpringMVC-web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:417)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:918)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at com.pp.repository.LoginRepository.logDetails(LoginRepository.java:16)
    at com.pp.service.LoginService.serLogin(LoginService.java:17)
    at com.pp.controller.LoginController.saveLogin(LoginController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at
```

I am actually checking here whether the data entered while logging is present in database or not. If the data is `null` then list will be `null`, and it sends back to login else to the homepage.
Can anyone help me with it.

Comment: not sure if this work but I haven't used single quotes '' around ?.. try by removing that one

Answer (score 0):

JPQL-style [positional parameters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api-positional-parameter-example) are declared using a question mark followed by an ordinal - `?1`, `?2`. *The ordinals start with 1.* Just like with named parameters, positional parameters can also appear multiple times in a query.

So, you should correct your query in this way:

```
select s.email, s.password from Student s where s.email=?1 and s.password=?2
```